# making Boxplot with 3 variables in r

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to make a boxplot in r but I struggle with grouping the boxplot﻿ by a third variable.

I want to have boxplots- all on one y-axes (score on a treatment outcome questionnaire), called HAMD)) -

for weeks 0-5 (called week)

and all twice for two treatment groups (called Treatment).

I made two boxplots with

> boxplot(MP$HAMD ~ MP$week)

and six with

> boxplot(MP$HAMD ~ MP$Treatment)

But now I want 12 boxplots together, each per week per treatment.
How can I do this in r?

By all means thank you very much.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here:  http://bit.ly/SORepro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `interaction` function and Base graphics:

```
boxplot( HAMD ~ interaction(treatment,week), data=MP )
boxplot( HAMD ~ interaction(week,treatment), data=MP )
boxplot( HAMD ~ interaction(week,treatment), data=MP,
    at= c(1:6, 8:13) )
```

And here is one option using the lattice package:

```
library(lattice)
bwplot( HAMD ~ week|treatment, data=MP )
bwplot( HAMD ~ treatment|week, data=MP )
bwplot( HAMD ~ treatment|week, data=MP, layout=c(6,1) )
```

And an option using the ggplot2 package:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(interaction(treatment,week), HAMD, data=MP, geom="boxplot")
p
p + aes(fill=week)
```