# R ggplot2 - How to plot 2 boxplots on the same x value

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

suppose I have two boxplots.

```
trial1 <- ggplot(completionTime, aes(fill=Condition, x=Scenario, y=Trial1))
trial1 + geom_boxplot()+geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) + ylim(0, 160)

trial2 <- ggplot(completionTime, aes(fill=Condition, x=Scenario, y=Trial2))
trial2 + geom_boxplot()+geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) + ylim(0, 160)
```

How can I plot trial 1 and trial 2 on the same plot and same respective X? they have the same range of y.

I looked at geom_boxplot(position="identity"), but that plots the two conditions(fill) on the same X.

I want to plot two y column on the same X.

---

Edit: the dataset

```
User Condition Scenario Trial1 Trial2
1     1        ME        a     67     41
2     1        ME        b     70     42
3     1        ME        c     40     15
4     1        ME        d     65     23
5     1        ME        e     45     45
6     1        SE        a    100     34
7     1        SE        b     54     23
8     1        SE        c     70     23
9     1        SE        d     56     15
10    1        SE        e     30     20
11    2        ME        a     42     23
12    2        ME        b     22     12
13    2        ME        c     28      8
14    2        ME        d     22      8
15    2        ME        e     38     37
16    2        SE        a     59     18
17    2        SE        b     65     14
18    2        SE        c     75      7
19    2        SE        d     37      9
20    2        SE        e     31      7
```

dput()

```
structure(list(User = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Condition = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ME", "SE"), class = "factor"), Scenario = 
structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), 
Trial1 = c(67L, 70L, 40L, 65L, 45L, 100L, 54L, 70L, 56L, 
30L, 42L, 22L, 28L, 22L, 38L, 59L, 65L, 75L, 37L, 31L), Trial2 = c(41L, 
42L, 15L, 23L, 45L, 34L, 23L, 23L, 15L, 20L, 23L, 12L, 8L, 
8L, 37L, 18L, 14L, 7L, 9L, 7L)), .Names = c("User", "Condition", 
"Scenario", "Trial1", "Trial2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: Could you add the dataset using dput() to make a reproducible example?

Comment: Sounds like you need to reshape this data from wide to long; _i.e._ put the values for `trial1` and `trial2` in one `y` column. But we need to see some data.

Comment: thanks, so I guess I have 3 conditions I want to plot in one plot?(condition/scenario/trial). I only know how to do 2..and I don't want to facet one of the conditions.

Comment: Difficult to see how you can avoid faceting something with > 2 factors and boxplots.

Comment: You could try using `interaction` as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187432/making-boxplot-with-3-variables-in-r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `interaction` to combine two of your factors and plot against a third. For example, assuming you want to fill by condition as in your original code:

```
library(tidyr)
completionTime %>% 
gather(trial, value, -Scenario, -Condition, -User) %>%
ggplot(aes(interaction(Scenario, trial), value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Condition))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: thanks. although I was originally wondering wether it would be possible to plot e.g. a.Trial2 under a.Trial1 (maybe with a different color), but maybe that kind of plot doesn't make sense or is a limitation of ggplot2. Anyways this is a good solution.